# Are there Unicode characters like these?

Tags: unicode

Are these findable? I've turned them myself because I could only find left and right. I want it to be the text of my buttons.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's `⌃` (U+2303 UP ARROWHEAD) and `⌄` (U+2304 DOWN ARROWHEAD).

Comment: That's not good enough, it has to look like these above..

Comment: The exact appearance will depend on the font.

Comment: If you need a very specific look, then you will never find an exact match in different fonts. Create a single svg image to your liking and rotate that by means of css. Fast and trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The closest match is probably:

- PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL LEFT ANGLE BRACKET (U+FE3F): ︿
- PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL RIGHT ANGLE BRACKET (U+FE40): ﹀

Technically, these are punctuation characters from the CJK compatibility block used for vertical writing systems. What you're really looking for is an arrow-like symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a special font, like [FontAwesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/). Check out [chevron-up](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/chevron-up/) and [chevron-down](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/chevron-down/).

I have to agree with some other responder, though, that SVG or even a sprite image would be better. You can set the text to be the unicode characters and [style the element](http://stopdesign.com/archive/2003/03/07/replace-text.html) to show the image, so that selecting it and copying would give you the text.

Comment: Don't blame the font for stupid browser implementations.

Comment: It's OK. I am used to people anonymously downvoting stuff without any actual opinion to back it off. I am using FontAwesome on my blog and it works for all the scenarios I tested, though. I will have to watch the video more carefully later. Thanks!